# Juno SR1 can't launch CDT projects anmore

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I just updated to Juno SR1 and CDT Version: 8.1.1. and now I cannot launch (run or debug) any CDT project anymore.

The error I get: Unable to launch. The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches.

To be sure I just added a new "Hello World C++" project. Compiles fine, cannot be launched.

If I look under Run - Run Configurations I cannot see any option that would sense for CDT project.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem in Juno. I solved it by reinstalling the "C/C++ Development Tools" from the same Eclipse:

Help -> Install New Software ...

Introducing "work with: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno" and selecting the CDT as the image:

[image: Install New Software]

After downloading and rebooting my "Run Configurations" now has the option to "C/C++ Application":

[image: Run Configurations]